# Convert error to map or struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

Just started with Go and currently trying to create a REST API. Using `gorm` & `gin` to do the same. Where am stuck is, am trying to fetch a value from the `error` object, but am not able to do that in a straight forward way.

The `error` type, if I know correctly, just hasa an `Error` method available, which gives whatever is in the `Message` part of the object. This is the error object I have.

```
{
    "Severity": "ERROR",
    "Code": "23505",
    "Message": "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uix_users_email\"",
    "Detail": "Key (email)=(johndoe@gmail.com) already exists.",
    "Hint": "",
    "Position": "",
    "InternalPosition": "",
    "InternalQuery": "",
    "Where": "",
    "Schema": "public",
    "Table": "users",
    "Column": "",
    "DataTypeName": "",
    "Constraint": "uix_users_email",
    "File": "nbtinsert.c",
    "Line": "433",
    "Routine": "_bt_check_unique"
}
```

Now, what I want to do is, access the `Detail` key, and am a bit confused. This is what I have currently done to be able to achieve this:

```
if err := a.DB.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
    val, _ := json.Marshal(err)
    m := make(map[string]string)
    json.Unmarshal(val, &m)
    context.JSON(422, gin.H{"error": m["Detail"]})
    return
}
```

But this seems like an overkill. I have to `Marshal` the error, then `Unmarshal` it into a map & then finally use it.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: It's just a struct, try accessing the fields.

Comment: Tried that, throws an error. The only method available is `Error`

Comment: What type is `Error`? What package is it defined in?

Comment: It is an interface type.

Comment: If the underlying type is exported by the package that generates the error you can use type assertion.

Comment: Then you can use a simple type assertion to coerce it to the underlying type, and then access the fields. But you still need to figure out what the actual type is and what package it's defined in - "it's an interface type" doesn't answer those questions.

Comment: And if the underlying type is unexported you can use `reflect` package to get to the `Detail` field.

Comment: @Adrian The type of error is `*pq.Error`. The `lib/pq` package is being used by `gorm` internally.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the suggestion, will try it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assert it to `pq.Error` and access the fields [as explained in the `pq` docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Errors):

```
if err, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
    fmt.Println("pq error:", err.Code.Name())
    // Or whatever other field(s) you need
}
```

The [full type is also documented](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error).

Comment: This works when I explicitly import the `github.com/lib/pq` package. The same package is imported as a side effect in the `gorm` package. Would the same type be available via `gorm`, or I will have to import the `lib/pq` package?